# How to clean, free space?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have on openembedded build dir

```
92G tmp
21G tmp-glibc
```

How to clean unneeded files? Old versions, abandoned targets, cache...

Is there any options to bitbake not to make copy of dependensies to each recipe?

I want delete all not needed for one selected task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just delete `tmp` whenever, as everything in there can be rebuilt if required.  Using the `rm_work` class will delete the work directories of completed builds and actually only has a very small impact on build times, especially if you tune the mount parameters so the write cache timeout is more than a few seconds, as a recipe can often build and be deleted before it needs to even be written to disk.

sstate-cache is all cache, as the name suggests.  There are tools such as `sstate-cache-management` to selectively prune, but the easier way is to just delete everything that hasn't been accessed for a while.  This will delete everything that hasn't been accessed for two months:

```
$ find /path/to/sstate-cache -type f -atime +60 -delete
```

Comment: you can remove tmp folder and it will retrieve compilation results from sstate-cache so you don't need to recompile everything.

Comment: This assumes you have atime turned on for the filesystem which is often not the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rm-work` class to cut down the accumulated disk usage by builds quite a bit. (see [rm_work.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/rm_work.bbclass)). Yet be aware that this on the other hand makes rebuilds potentially take longer, depending on the exact situation.

For a way to selectively clean the caches, I don't think that there is any.